# Deleting ".part" files from folder with PHP

Tags: php, partial, delete-file, unlink

I'm using the following to delete all files from the specified directory.

```
$files = glob('path/to/temp/*');
foreach($files as $file){
if(is_file($file)) 
unlink($file);
}
```

It removes everything other than partially uploaded files eg : **myfile.mp3.part**

I've tried specifying .part in the file path just to see if I can force it that way :

```
$files = glob('path/to/temp/*.part');
```

But that doesn't work either.
Am I missing something here? Is there a different method for deleting non-active partial files?

Answer (score 1):

```
$files = scandir('/path/to/temp');

foreach($files as $key => $file) {
    if ( preg_match('/.*?\.part$/', $file) ) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Grant do you set absolute path?

Comment: Yes but i'm using a variable pulled from a GET in the path, could this be why? /path/to/temp/{$myVar}

Comment: My original code deletes every other file in the folder except the .part ones so I know it's working path wise.

Comment: I saw you said it is "plupload", but in plupload already have code for remove *.part file. What your version plupload?

Comment: Yes I know @waki, latest version, set to remove part files but doesn't work. If it did I wouldn't have had to try doing it with my own php script :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something likes this to delete all files in a folder.

```
$dir = "/path/to/temp";
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file){
    $path = $dir."/".$file;
    if(is_file($path)) unlink($path);
}
```

Comment: where did u define `$path` ?

Comment: Sorry, wrong variable used. I've edited it to $file.

Comment: Doesn't work either, .part files are still in there.

Comment: I guess this files are locked, in use by another application or your webserver/php don't have the rights to delete this file.

Comment: That is possible, they are being uploaded via the plupload engine. Is there anyway to change the perms on these files before deleting them maybe?

Comment: I went into the server and manually changed the .part files to 777, still can't delete them with the script?

Comment: You must find out what exactly the problem is. Maybe you can try to use `chmod($path, 0777)` before deleting but i don't think that this is helping if your webserver doesn't have the permission to do this. Enabling also `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before the delete block maybe give you some mor information. If the file is "in use" than this file possibly cannot be deleted by PHP itself.

Comment: Plupload - I think this is also the Web Upload Script. Than "in use" possibly caused by the webserver itself. Stop and start the webserver again maybe release the lock.

Comment: Getting no error messages in the log about this at all? There are over 100 people uploading into separate folders at any given time, webserver restart isn't a viable option here i'm afraid.

Comment: Than don't care about the files you can't delete. They locked for a good reason and shouldn't be deleteable. Have you checked if everytime the same file isn't deletable or is it every time another file?